# ¿Es posible descargar e integrar APIs a Android Studio sin tener internet en la PC que contiene el programa?

Tags: android, android-studio, windows, api

Tengo Android Studio en una PC de mesa con Windows 8.1, pero por ahora no tengo internet en dicho equipo. El equipo que tengo no soporta la emulación del emulador de android, por lo cual deseaba usar mi celular Android para realizar las pruebas de mi aplicación.

La API necesaria para mi celular es la 4.4.2 y sólo me encuentro con la api 4.2, por lo cual mi pregunta es: ¿Puedo descargar la API necesaria desde algún sitio web desde otro PC para luego implementarla en Android Studio y el mismo funcione con mi celular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se puede.

Los pasos son:

1. Descargar [android-17_r03.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-17_r03.zip)
2. Ir a la carpeta donde se encuentra tus archivos SDK de Android en tu PC. La ruta sería Android/Sdk/platforms/
3. Descomprimir el archivo que recién descargaste dentro de la ruta Android/Sdk/platforms/. El nombre de la carpeta sería android-4.2.2
4. Descargar [sources-17_r01.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-17_r01.zip)
5. Ir a la carpeta donde se encuentra tus archivos SDK de Android en tu PC. La ruta sería Android/Sdk/sources/
6. Descomprimir el archivo que recién descargaste en Android/Sdk/sources/.
7. Se va a crear una carpeta llamada **src**.
8. Cambiamos el nombre de la carpeta por **android-4.2.2**.
9. Ya tenes la API 17 en tu equipo

[image: Android API 17]

Obs:

- Acabo de probar en mi equipo y me funciona.
- Asumo que tenes instalado Android SDK Platform-Tools y Android SDK Tools

Comment: Muchas gracias! la verdad era algo así lo que deseaba, la solución de David Isla no esta nada mal pero en el computador en el que estoy no puedo bajarme el Android Studio ya que es muy viejo e incluso usando XP se guinda con Chrome. ¿Desde donde puedo conseguir otras apis? solo modificando ese enlace para colocar el numero de api crees que funcione? o tienes alguna web que entregue dichas apis?

Comment: Reemplaza por le numero de api. A mi me funciono con la API 21. Caso que no te funciones, busca en google por la API especifica.

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo y funciona perfecto mas tarde me paso a mi pc y te digo si me ha funcionado o no este método igual muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes instalar Android Studio en otro PC, descargar lo que necesites y después llevarte la carpeta donde hayas configurado el SDK de Android al PC que no tienes internet y sustituirla.

Por otro lado, dices que no te funciona el emulador, entiendo que es porque tu PC no admite la tecnología HAXM, ¿cierto?.

Si fuera ese el caso, siempre puedes crear un dispositivo con una imagen ARM en lugar de x86/x64. En el AVD, crea un nuevo dispositivo y elige una imagen ARM. Completa el proceso y tendrás un emulador más lento, pero funcional.

Ten en cuenta que es posible que también necesites descargar de internet la imagen ARM de la versión Android que necesites (4.2, 4.2.2, etc.).

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias! La verdad esa idea de instalar android studio y copiar la carpeta con la api necesaria si se me había pasado por la cabeza pero no estaba seguro de que se pudiera lograr. En respuesta a lo de la imagen ARM que tanto baja la velocidad del emulador? de por si mi computador no es demasiado potente... Cuento con 2 de RAM y un procesador de 4Ghz Intel...

Comment: Bufff... es dificil de decir, pero quizás unas 10 veces más lento. Pero te aseguro que probarlo en tu móvil será mucho peor, ten en cuenta que el emulador te brindará opciones muy útiles según el desarrollo que necesites (simular pérdidas de conexión, Wifi, 3G, llamadas entrantes, sms y un largo etc.)

Comment: Pfff... Demasiado... Ya de por si según he leido el emulador de Android es realmente lento... Y..
Si... Eso lo he tomado en cuenta... Por ahora pienso usarlo simplemente con el celular, pronto probaré en una laptop que tiene un procesador mas potente y mayor RAM (Sin contar que no esta llena de millones de cosas) Así que debería correr mucho mejor allí. Igual muchas gracias bro.